# Reverse states on hover with Less

Tags: css, less, less-mixins

I have the following LESS code:

```
.favourite-action-link {
    &:after {
        color:@grey;
        content: '\e836';
    }
    &.is-favourite:after {
        color:@red;
        content: '\e811';
    }
    &:hover {
        &:after {
            color:@red;
            content: '\e811';
        }
        &.is-favourite:after {
            color:@grey;
            content: '\e836';
        }
    }
}
```

With the essential goal being that there is a normal state and a hover state, that are reversed when another class is present. I'll be repeating this for other actions (eg `.share-action-link`, `.review-action-link` etc) and this just seems messy the way I have it. Is there a way to create a mixin such that I could provide this like so:

```
.favourite-action-link {
    &:after {
        color:@grey;
        content: '\e836';
        &:hover {
            color:@red;
            content: '\e811';
        }
        .reverseOnClass(is-favourite);
    }
}
```

Or something like that? The only way I can think of so far would be to do:

```
.favourite-action-link {
    &:after {
        color:@grey;
        content: '\e836';
    }
    &.active:after {
        color:@red;
        content: '\e811';
    }
}
```

and then to use jQuery instead to do the hover - toggling `.active` on `(isHovering XOR hasClass(is-favourite))` - but turning LESS into LESS + jQuery is the opposite of fixing a mess/maintainability issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would really recommend writing it like below because it keeps the code simple and easy to read.

```css
.favourite-action-link {
  &:after, &.is-favourite:hover:after {
    color: @grey;
    content: '\e836';
  }
  &:hover:after, &.is-favourite:after {
    color: @red;
    content: '\e811';
  }
}
```

But if you really want to use a mixin to avoid repeating the selectors then you could write it like below. This mixin takes two rulesets as input and they are applied to the required selectors.

```css
.favourite-action-link {
  .rules-gen(
    {
      color: @grey;
      content: '\e836';
    };
    {
      color: @red;
      content: '\e811';
    }
  );
}

.rules-gen(@rule1; @rule2){
  &:after, &.is-favourite:hover:after {
    @rule1();
  }
  &:hover:after, &.is-favourite:after {
    @rule2();
  }
}
```

In both these methods, the selectors are also grouped and that also means reduced lines of code.

[**Demo**](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.favourite-action-link%20%7B%5Cn%20%20.rules-gen(%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3A%20grey%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20content%3A%20'%5C%5Ce836'%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3A%20red%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20content%3A%20'%5C%5Ce811'%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.share-action-link%20%7B%5Cn%20%20.rules-gen(%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3A%20yellow%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20content%3A%20'%5C%5Ce836'%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3A%20gold%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20content%3A%20'%5C%5Ce811'%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.rules-gen(%40rule1%3B%20%40rule2)%7B%5Cn%20%20%26%3Aafter%2C%20%26.is-favourite%3Ahover%3Aafter%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40rule1()%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%26%3Ahover%3Aafter%2C%20%26.is-favourite%3Aafter%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40rule2()%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D)

---

Or, if the extra class is not always `is-favourite` and it could also be something else then you could pass it also to the mixin as a parameter like below:

```css
.favourite-action-link {
  .rules-gen(
    {
      color: grey;
      content: '\e836';
    };
    {
      color: red;
      content: '\e811';
    };
    ~"is-favourite"
  );
}

.share-action-link {
  .rules-gen(
    {
      color: yellow;
      content: '\e836';
    };
    {
      color: gold;
      content: '\e811';
    };
    ~"active"
  );
}

.rules-gen(@rule1; @rule2; @addedClass){
  &:after, &.@{addedClass}:hover:after {
    @rule1();
  }
  &:hover:after, &.@{addedClass}:after {
    @rule2();
  }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.favourite-action-link%20%7B%5Cn%20%20.rules-gen(%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3A%20grey%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20content%3A%20'%5C%5Ce836'%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3A%20red%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20content%3A%20'%5C%5Ce811'%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%5Cn%20%20%5Ct~%5C%22is-favourite%5C%22%5Cn%20%20)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.share-action-link%20%7B%5Cn%20%20.rules-gen(%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3A%20yellow%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20content%3A%20'%5C%5Ce836'%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3A%20gold%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20content%3A%20'%5C%5Ce811'%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%5Cn%20%20%5Ct~%5C%22active%5C%22%5Cn%20%20)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.rules-gen(%40rule1%3B%20%40rule2%3B%20%40addedClass)%7B%5Cn%20%20%26%3Aafter%2C%20%26.%40%7BaddedClass%7D%3Ahover%3Aafter%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40rule1()%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%26%3Ahover%3Aafter%2C%20%26.%40%7BaddedClass%7D%3Aafter%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40rule2()%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D)

Comment: I wasn't tied to a mixin for any particular reason - I can't believe I looked at it for as long as I did and didn't simplify the selectors like you have there first. That's exactly what I need, thanks.